# Generated SVG file using fabric JS with applied opacity to image object - show differently as compareing color in browser and inkscape

Tags: fabricjs, inkscape

I am using fabric JS 1.6.2. And after applied opacity to image object, generated SVG File. This svg file open in browser & InkScape. Both show much different in color.

Actually proof of canvas is generated different in color with SVG of InkScape. This issue is happened while applied opacity.

SVG With Browser:

[image]

Same Svg with InkScape

[image]

Original Image which added in design:

[image]

Here is content of SVG FILE :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="380" height="380" viewBox="0 0 380 380" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.7.13</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(190 174) scale(0.543338 0.543338)">
<image xlink:href="1-original.jpg" x="-386.5" y="-500" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 0.5;" width="773" height="1000" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a bug with 0.91 (I could reproduce that it looks paler there). Update to 0.92.3 (looked exactly the same as in the browser there).